# Building a SSRS report with Subreports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subreport

I have a Report, which needs to display 4 different sub reports. I have implemented this report by taking a table with 4 rows and placing a sub-report in each row. 
Now, when I run the report, the reports are not being displayed in the order in which I arranged in the table.

Am I missing any thing?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is now solved. The problem was w.r.t. indentation. I changed the page width and height to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if there is any sorting in the row group properties of the table or in the tablix properties. If any, remove and then run the report.

Comment: the problem is now solved. The problem was WRT indentation. I changed the page properties and the problem is solbed. Thanks for replyinh.